# How do I pass back a user selection of YES/NO

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, alert

Right now the current script is the below where someone selects a menu option, and the name is deleted.

I'd like to provide a prompt to confirm this selection. Where yes would delete the name, and they would get their defaultname back and no would just basically mean "cancel"

```
function deleteSomething()
{
    deletename('name')
    addDefaultname()
}
    function deletename(value) {
    PropertyService.getUserproperties().deleteProperty(value)
}
```

Here's what I've come up:

```
function deleteSomething()
{ deletename('name') 
if('YES') 
{ addDefaultName() 
} 
else {
}
}

function deleteSomething(value){
var result=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Are you sure you want to delete this name?",  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO)

if(result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {

}
else
{

}
}
```

`

I'm not that skilled in programming, but trying to figure out how to pass back the user selection.

Comment: Look at Spreadsheet.getUi()

Answer (score 1):

```
function askQuestion() {
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Do you wish to continue?",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(r.getSelectedButton  == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
    //if yes
  } else {
    // must be no this way
  }
}
```

How do I pass r back to deleteSomething()?

```
function askQuestion() {
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Do you wish to continue?",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  return r;
}

function doSomething(r=askQuestion()) {
  //doSomething code
}
```

Comment: How do I pass r back to deleteSomething() which will then use r to be in the if statement.